# Is there a way to see the generated sql after oci_bind_by_name?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am working on an old PHP web app that uses Oracle as a backend. I don't have direct access to this database.

In the old app they are using `str_replace`s instead of `oci_bind_by_name` to replace variables on the sql. I want to change this, but I want to do so while avoiding breaking up something. So I'm writing some tests before executing the sql.

I'd like to compare the old generated sql with the one after using `oci_bind_by_name` but I cannot find a way to see the "bound" sql.

Is there such a way?

Comment: Not directly, because the equivalent SQL never exists, at least not outside of the database itself, you have to create it by hand (which isn't much of a test)

Comment: The best test is to see that it returns the same records as the original

Comment: I'll settle for this, though it prevents me from testing insert or update queries. Thanks for the answer.